# E: Unable to locate package ros-diamondback-nxtall - installing on ubuntu 16.04 possible?

Tags: nxt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am attempting to install ROS for NXT Diamondback on my Ubuntu 16.04. Is this even possible?

I am going through the following steps:
http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/NXT/diamondback

However, I encounter the following issues:

```
daniel@beepboop:~/Downloads$ sudo restart udev
restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

when I get to that stage. I rebooted my computer instead.

For step 1.4, I did the following instead:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

which appeared to work.

When I get to step 1.6, apt-get cannot find the package:

```
daniel@beepboop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-nxtall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-diamondback-nxtall
```

Do I have any options here other than installing another version of ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247666/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-diamondback-nxtall---installing-on-ubuntu-16.04-possible?/) by [DanielPBak](https://answers.ros.org/users/28485/danielpbak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am attempting to install ROS for NXT Diamondback on my Ubuntu 16.04. Is this even possible?

No, unfortunately not (at least not the 'vanilla' version of the NXT packages).

> When I get to step 1.6, apt-get cannot find the package:

> ```
> daniel@beepboop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-nxtall
> ```

which makes sense, as only *ROS Kinetic* is supported on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial).

The NXT stacks are rather old, and I remember various people making various efforts to port them to newer versions of ROS. Some related links:

- [ros-sig-nxt](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ros-sig-nxt)
- [Lego NXT-ROS working on Groovy Galapagos?](http://answers.ros.org/question/52836)
- [Anyway to install ROS-NXT on Trusty?](http://answers.ros.org/question/204161)
- [Version of Ubuntu and ROS for NXT and Turtlebot2](http://answers.ros.org/question/173011)
- [github.com/dbworth/NXT-ROS](https://github.com/dbworth/NXT-ROS)

There appear to be various forks of the original NXT packages on Github, perhaps some of those work on newer ROS versions. I have no personal experience with any of those, so you'll have to test them out.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1